# Azure Devops Pipeline - How to pass variable into Powershell function

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I have Yaml pipeline with powershell task:

```
       - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: filePath
          filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\folder\script.ps1
          arguments: > 
            -SP_TenantId "$(SP_TenantId)"
            -ProjectName "${{parameters.ProjectName}}"
```

The script.ps1 has a PS Function which starts with mandatory parameters from Yaml arguments

```
    param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$SP_TenantId,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$ProjectName,

)
```

After running the pipeline I've got an error telling that env are missing:

```
Get-GraphToken : Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: SP_TenantId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I compare your snippet with a pipeline of mine, I've recognized some differences according to providing the arguments: can you try it that way?

```
inputs:
  targetType: filePath
  filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\folder\script.ps1
  arguments: '-SP_TenantId:"$(SP_TenantId)" -ProjectName:"${{parameters.ProjectName}}"'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Devops Pipeline - How to pass variable into Powershell function

You could try to remove the **second** **comma** in the `script.ps1`:

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$SP_TenantId,
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string]$ProjectName
```

)

I test it, it works fine on my side. Please check it.